# getting an error in android studio while trying to build my project

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am in a class where we are working in a group and we are using GitHub to share the project and work on it through that way
it was working fine that way for a very long time but all of the sudden using the android emulator one day during class when I built the project and closed it normally the emulator was just a black screen
so I figured it bugged out or something and reinstalled a new emulator through android studio and now I get this

[image]

I have tried the repair IDE on android studio and nothing changed I cleared my gradlew caches multiple times nothing changed I am at my wits end here
I thought it was the emulator as a whole but it still builds my other projects and runs them without error so now I'm even more confused

Comment: Hi @Nickelas Chem. Try this command and run your project again (it may take long time to finish) --> flutter pub cache repair

Comment: I have now tried flutter pub cache repair running it in the local terminal and in gradlew it reinstalled 147 packages both times and both times still the same error @Aks

Comment: You also need to restart the terminal once you clean cache and then run pub get again and then pub run

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)